# Accesses local folder, iterates through files renaming them to lowercase, but doesn't persist

Tags: c

Purpose: To rename files contained within directory to lowercase.

What I know: Code using fts library, etc. was taken from this very helpful individual. https://keramida.wordpress.com/2009/07/05/fts3-or-avoiding-to-reinvent-the-wheel/.

Using GDB, I can walk through the code and see that in fact, the filesbecome lowercase (Ex. DSC_2048.JPG becomes dsc_2048.jpg). However, after I run the program, I go back to check the folder that contains those files, and they are all still named in uppercase.

Here is my code snippet that renames to lowercase:

```
    case FTS_F:
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(p->fts_name); i++)
        {
            p->fts_name[i] = tolower(p->fts_name[i]);
        }
        break;
    }
```

p is the pointer to the structure containing the file info. FTS_F is the designation by fts that it is a "normal file". Once it knows it is a normal file, it runs this case.

Could the problem be that the structure provided is a copy of the contents, and not the contents themselves? If so, how can I go about doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is merely (dangerously) writing the program memory that stores the filename that was read, you aren't actually telling the OS to change the name in the filesystem. To do that, use [rename](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/rename.html).

Comment: Could you go into more detail? If I'm changing the file name in memory, would that not automatically communicate to the OS that the name has changed? Isn't that where it reads the info on the file from?

 And I realize that overwriting memory can be dangerous, but in this case I'm accessing a specific part of a struct that contains the information and changing the name from one case to another. Could you clarify?

Thank you, asking in order to learn.

Comment: The in-memory representation of the directory structure is not the same as the data stored on disk that permanently records the actual file system structure. The OS can be notified of writes to general pages of memory (which is how virtual memory is implemented), but it is not at this sort of granularity... rather than watching a specific region of memory, the standard practice in programming is to "encapsulate" the internals by forcing the information to be read / modified through functions (such as "rename") that maintain the abstraction's invariants.